# Video tag sticking issue

Tags: html, css, video, tags

I want the video tag to stick to the top (or bottom from the element above the video tag). When one resizes the window with the current code I am using, the video element will also remove itself from the top (or bottom from the element above in hierarchy in HTML). Is there a way to prevent the video coming loose from its top? I assume this is because the video tag is trying to keep its ratio and might has something to do with the width: 100%.

I made a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/651j9b5h/) and here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="background-video">
  <video autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="somevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background-video
{
    position: relative;
}

.background-video video
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1080px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

So how do I make it so that the video tag doesn't resize in an unpleasant way and still fills the space correctly?

Comment: you have the height set to 1080px, but the width to 100%. So the height will always stay the same, but the width will scale. Have you tried using `height: auto`

Comment: also, your fiddle doesn't work as you need to link to an actual video

Comment: Yeah but it's not about the video itself, just the video tag, it's stupposed to be "fill in any video source you want" case.

Comment: I think simply putting height on auto was the fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to you CSS this line for responsive elements of video, image, iframe, etc.

CSS

```
audio, iframe, img, video { 
max-width: 100%; 
}
```